# Line Integral centered at (1/2,0)

Tags: integration, line-integrals

Evaluate $\int_C (x + y)\text ds$, where $C$ is the circle centred at $(1/2, 0)$ with radius $1/2$.

parametrise

$$x=\frac12\cos(t) \tag1$$

$$y=\frac12\sin(t)\tag2$$

$2\pi\geq t\geq0$

$$ds=\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}$$
$$=\sqrt{\left(\frac12\right)^2-\sin^2(t)+\left(\frac12\right)^2\cos^2(t)}$$

$$=\sqrt{-(1)^2\left(\frac12\right)^2\sin^2(t)+\left(\frac12\right)^2\cos^2(t)}$$

$$=\sqrt{-(1)^2\left(\frac12\right)^2\left(\sin^2(t)+\cos^2(t)\right)}$$

$$ds=\frac12$$

$$\int \left[\frac12\cos(t) + \frac12\sin(t)\right]\cdot\frac12 dt$$ , where $2\pi\geq t\geq0$

I evaluated this integral and got 0. I don't think this is correct though. Does the origin of this circle starting at $(1/2,0)$ change the integral?

Comment: I having difficulty understanding your post. Here is mathjax, as shown in http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: What makes you that that you got the wrong answer?

Comment: your $x$ should be $x=1/2+1/2\cos(t)$.

Comment: I see path integrals as like the volume of something like a curtain. I hope that makes sense without a picture. When I get an answer of 0 I assumed it was incorrect because the area cannot equal 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two reasonable parameterizations as I see it. The first is as all have recommended, simply translate the origin of polar coordinates to the center of the circle and then $x=\frac12+\frac12\cos t$ and $y=\frac12\sin t$, so
$$ds=\sqrt{(dx)^2+(dy)^2}=\sqrt{\left(-\frac12\sin t\right)^2+\left(\frac12\cos t\right)^2}\,dt=\frac12dt$$
So the integral is
$$I=\int_0^{2\pi}\left[\frac12+\frac12\cos t+\frac12\sin t\right]\cdot\frac12dt=\frac14(2\pi)(1+0+0)=\frac{\pi}2$$
Where we have used the average value of $1$ of $1$ and the average values of $\cos t$ and $\sin t$ of $0$ over the interval of length $2\pi$.

The other possibility is using the 'polar coordinate' version of the circle $r=\cos t$, $x=r\cos t=\cos^2t$, and $y=r\sin t=\sin t\cos t$, so
$$ds=\sqrt{(dx)^2+(dy)^2}=\sqrt{\left(-2\sin t\cos t\right)^2+\left(\cos^2t-\sin^2t\right)^2}=\sqrt{\left(\cos^2t+\sin^2t\right)^2}=dt$$
Then
$$I=\int_{-\frac{\pi}2}^{\frac{\pi}2}(\cos^2t+\sin t\cos t)dt=\pi(\frac12+0)=\frac{\pi}2$$
Where we have used the average value of $\cos^2t$ of $\frac12$ and of $\sin t\cos t=\frac12\sin2t$ of $0$ over the interval of length $\pi$.

You knew the answer up front because it should be the average value of $x$ plus the average value of $y$ over the curve times the arc length of the curve, so
$$I=\left(\frac12+0\right)(2\pi)(\frac12)=\frac{\pi}2$$
Where we have used the mensuration formula $s=2\pi r$ for the perimeter of a circle of radius $r$.

Answer (score 0):

Check your parametrization because the one you chose represents the circle of 1/2 radious but centered in $(0,0)$.

Comment: x= 1/2cos(t)-1/2
y= 1/2sin(t)

Comment: Well, $y$ is ok, but I think $x$ should be $x=1/2cos(t) + 1/2$ so when you compute $(x-1/2)^2+y^2$ you get $1/4$ and hence it will be the parametrization of the circle of radius $1/2$ centered at $(1/2,0)$.